# Can I use md-select and have one option select multiple options?

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material, md-select

I have the following small sample:

```
<md-select ng-model="selectedYears" multiple>
  <md-option>10 Years</md-option>
  <md-option value="2016">
  <md-option value="2015">
  <!--- more options -->
</md-select>
```

What I want is when the user selects the option that I labeled with "10 Years" above, the equivalent of the following should happen (instead of selecting the option)

```
$scope.selectedYears = [2016, 2015/*, ... */];
```

Comment: could you explain more, what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @PankajParkar, I hope it's better now, shortened it down a lot

Comment: checkout answer, I created Codepen as well for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put change event on your `select` so that whenever there is `10 years` have been selected that time you could last 10 years manually. Also you have to change `value` to `ng-value` so that value should be consider as of `number` type instead of `string`.

**Markup**

```
 <md-select ng-model="selectedYears" multiple ng-change="yearChanged(selectedYears)">
    <md-option ng-value="10">10 Years</md-option>
    <md-option ng-value="2016">2016</md-option>
    <md-option ng-value="2015">2015</md-option>
    <md-option ng-value="2014">2014</md-option>
    <md-option ng-value="2013">2013</md-option>
    <md-option ng-value="2012">2012</md-option>
    <md-option ng-value="2011">2011</md-option>
    <md-option ng-value="2010">2010</md-option>
    <md-option ng-value="2009">2009</md-option>
    <md-option ng-value="2008">2008</md-option>
  </md-select>
</md-select>
```

[**Forked Pen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNxjzx?editors=1010)

Comment: That works, but there are a few problems that make it hard to use in my case. First, I already have a ng-change method hooked up - a bit of a nuisance. Second, I'd have to keep the ng-value of the special option in sync with inside ng-change, something that is not quite obvious to any reader. To sum it up, this works, but probably won't pass codereview. Thanks for your effort though.

Comment: @WorldSEnder could you please eloborate what's problem with `ng-change` hook?

Comment: That I have to repeat the ng-value of the special option inside the hooked method. What I imagined was that all hooks are local to the md-option element in question. I'll use it though and let codereview decide if it's acceptable.